# Google Translate with a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-translate

I am working on Python with a CSV file where I would like to convert some columns to English language, I have been using Google Translate but it refers as they require a JSON file, is it possible to use Google Translate on a CSV file.

below is the error that I receive:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import goslate
from googletrans import Translator
from translate import Translator

df = pd.read_csv ("Johanna.csv", delimiter=',',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df. head (20)
translator= Translator()
df['habitat']=[str(x) for x in df['habitat']]
df['habitat_en']=df['habitat'].map(lambda x:translator.translate (x, src="PT",dest="en").text)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Also, why not write a script that converts from csv to json?

Comment: tried doing that got error:JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: take a look at this tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Comment: Thanks, @basilisk... I just tested and it worked super nice!

Answer (score 2):

To translate a CSV file you will need to:

1. Read the file using `pandas` library.
2. Iterate through all cells in the file one by one.
3. Translate each cell individually.

If you also wish to save the translated document as new CSV file, you will need to:

4. Save every translated cell to a python dictionary.
5. Convert the dictionary to pandas DataFrame.
6. Save the DataFrame as new CSV file.

There are not much of information provided in your description but I have prepared some code that does what you ask for. It translates a CSV file and saves the translated CSV file as a new CSV file called `transaltedCSV.csv`. You can find my [example code here](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Google%20Translate%20API/translate_csv_python.py) in GitHub.

My example is working with a CSV file that has two columns. Take the idea of the implementation and adjust the number columns based on your needs. Also change the `column1` and `column2` names to your column names accordingly.

---

If that doesn't solve your issue, please provide further details.

Comment: this is the error when i run the code written by me:"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: also, i tried to incorporate the one u suggested, i receive a similiar sort of error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'csv'"

Comment: I have tried to replicate your case and I have got the same error. Apparently the `.csv` is out of the string. So I am guessing that the error is coming from the `data = pd.read_csv('/home/cusnir/mine/translateCSV/test.csv')` line. Please make sure that the `.csv` is included in the `""` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing with same approach,like I have a csv file where i am iterating through column and translating each cell individually. Is there any way I could use the same technique since I have around 300 cells minimum in a csv and multiple csvs so it take a lottt of time